# How can I implement configurable java agent in runtime

Tags: java, jvm, byte-buddy, javaagents

In a static java agent,  we predefine the intercepted class and methods and related advice, the code may look like follows, which means when enter and exit class1.method1(), code in MyAdvice will be executed.

```
    public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
                .type("class1")
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
                        .method("method1")
                        .intercept(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class))
                ).installOn(instrumentation);

    Class MyAdvice{

      @Advice.OnMethodEnter
      public static void onBeforeExecute(@Advice.AllArguments Object[] params,
                                     @Advice.This Object agr0) {
      }
      @Advice.OnMethodExit
      public static void onAfterExecute() {
      }
}
```

However, the intercepted class and methods are predefined and hard-coded before the actual application start. Is there any approach or framework that, predefine some advice,  then the application start, and where we what to intercept can be dynamically configured through a config file in runtime? The config file may look like this:

```
{
   method: "method2",
   class: "class2",
   advice: "MyAdvice2"
}
```

which means I want intercept class2.method2() and MyAdvice2.class will be used.

Comment: You have hardcoded strings in your code and want replace them with values read from a configuration file. That’s a general programming task, entirely unrelated to the actual use case. Whether you use the strings for instrumentation, as a file name, network address, or color of a user interface, doesn’t change the way, how you read strings from a file and use them instead of hardcoded values. If you want a config file in JSON format, you need a JSON parser.

Comment: Well, I didn't describe my goal precisely, what I need is reading the config file in runtime after actual application start.

Comment: You can read the configuration file whenever you want. It’s still you who has to do it. This includes defining what determines the right time to do it. The Instrumentation API also doesn’t mind if you add class file transformers at a later time. Of course, load time transformation does only work if the affected class has not been loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

As for Holger's comment, he is of course right that you need to find a way to discover that your configuration has changed which has nothing to do with an agent. You can of course scan the file regularly from some thread, or register an HTTP endpoint to submit new data.

As for Byte Buddy, the `AgentBuilder` returns a `ResettableClassFileTransformer` which you can pass to a new `AgentBuilder` in its `patchOn` method. This will make Byte Buddy compute a minimal subset of classes that need to be updated after your changes. It will return a new class file transformer that allows you to repeat the process later with a new update.